# Vs2012 Unable to connect to Nuget with a proxy

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-2012, proxy, nuget

I am running Visual Studio 2012 in a VM (windows 7 64bit) and am having trouble getting to Nuget. The username i use on the VM is not the username i use to authenticate through the proxy so my devenv.exe.config file looks like this:

```
<system.net>
     <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="false" enabled="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True"/>
     </defaultProxy>
     <settings>
        <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"/>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

Initially when i opened Extensions and Updates i recieved the following message:

> A connection to the server could not be established because the following error(s) occurred:
>   There was no endpoint listening at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/Services/v2011/Extension.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   Unable to connect to the remote server
>   A connection attemp dailed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 65.52.103.91:80

After reading several articles I went to Tools -> options -> Environment -> Web Browser and clicked on the Internet Explorer options... button. I then went to connections -> Lan settings and although we use aconfiuration script i added a proxy server and clicked ok.

now the message has changed when going o online Extensions and Updates:

> A connection to the server could not be established because the following errors(s) occured:
>   The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The Authentication header recieved from the server was 'NTLM, Basic realm="Our Proxy Server".
>   The remote server returned an error:(401) Unauthorised.

So how do i get it to let me use the correct credentials to pass the proxy?

Comment: Yo, your proxy does not accept Anonymous connections, use a diff one.

Comment: No choice on proxies,  i have credetials but how do i get VS to use them on the proxy?

Comment: **Update:** So i have found something very interesting.  If i right click on the solution and "Manage NuGet Packages for solution" then i can access online packages, however i still cannot access this through the tools menu.

Comment: **Update 11-Jun-2013** I have found that by right clicking on the references in a project and selecting "Manage NuGet packages..." i am able to connect and install packages, although I am not 100% sure this is working correctly as I still had issues with the entity framework when it was installed this way. I am going to work with a data engineer and see if we can diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after much searching it ended up there was a firewall rule that was causing the issue.  After a new rule burn I can now access it via VS fine.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use the Windows Credential Manager?

You should be able register a Windows Credential that looks like this:

```
Internet or Network Address : *.mycompany.com
User Name                   : Your User Name
Password                    : Your Password
```

You could probably also limit the network address to just the proxy server.

Comment: Thanks Immo,  i think this might be what i need, but i am still working on geting it right.  I will update when I know some more.

Comment: **UPDATE:** I have tried this but still no luck.  no matter what i do i still see the same message.  It appears as if it is still trying to authnticate as anonymous, is there anyway to change this in the config?

Comment: Hmm, let me ping the NuGet folks. Stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks Immo, appreciate your ongoing support with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to come provide some guidance on how to get NuGet to communicate with https://nuget.org using NuGet's [proxy credentials configuration](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-settings), but it doesn't seem that's actually your problem.  You might need to do that once you get to where you're actually using NuGet though.

When you are going to Extensions and Updates from VS, this isn't NuGet, but rather the Extension Gallery you're connecting to.

I recommend opening your browser and going to http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/

Does that work?  If not, then you have a more general proxy issue than what you're experiencing within Visual Studio.  If it does, then you know your proxy credential issue is specific to Visual Studio and you can try to find the right way to configure VS to prompt you for your proxy credentials (I tried to search around a bit but haven't found the right answer yet).

Comment: Hi,  thanks for your reply.  I can get to http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/
 with no issues at all.  I think this is a Visual Studio proxy issue, the biggest issue that my account that i log onto the dev VM is not the same account as the account i use for the proxy.

Comment: Can you browse to http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ via VS's internal web browser window? You can launch it via **View | Other Windows | Web Browser**.

Comment: Yes i can view it successfully.